# Problem gathering data from Firebase RealtimeDatabase (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having an issue while gathering data from a node on Firebase. I got a variable named `stockBuy`, I have run my app on debug mode and it gets the value correctly but out of `onDataChange()` my variable becomes to be 1 instead of the value from firebase + 1 as I have on this line `stockBuy = stockBuy + 1;`

Here you can see my code

```
private void deleteProduct(final int position){
    mDataBase3 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
    mDataBase4 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Wishes");
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products").child(MainActivity.carrito.get(position).getId());

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            stockBuy = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("stock").getValue().toString());          
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });

    stockBuy = stockBuy + 1;

    mDataBase3.child(MainActivity.carrito.get(position).getId()).child("stock").setValue(stockBuy);
    mDataBase4.child(userUid).child(MainActivity.carrito.get(position).getId()).child("stock").setValue(stockBuy);

    MainActivity.carrito.remove(position);

    this.cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, which means that `onDataChange` may execute much later than you expect. If you place breakpoints or add some logging, you can see that `stockBuy = stockBuy + 1;` runs before `stockBuy = Integer.parseInt` is ever called, which explains the problem.

Any code that needs the data from the database needs to be inside `onDataChange` or be called from there. So the simplest fix is:

```
private void deleteProduct(final int position){
    mDataBase3 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
    mDataBase4 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Wishes");
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products").child(MainActivity.carrito.get(position).getId());

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            stockBuy = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("stock").getValue().toString());          

            stockBuy = stockBuy + 1;

            mDataBase3.child(MainActivity.carrito.get(position).getId()).child("stock").setValue(stockBuy);
            mDataBase4.child(userUid).child(MainActivity.carrito.get(position).getId()).child("stock").setValue(stockBuy);

            MainActivity.carrito.remove(position);

            this.cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            throw error.toException();
        }
    });
}
```

Also see:

- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)